# Считаете ли Вы это правильным?

Tags: этикет

Насколько я знаю, **ты-общение** используется только в кругу знакомых или близких людей. Вот меня заинтересовал вопрос: можно ли считать учительницу русского языка быдлом в том случае, если она разговаривает на **ты** со своими учениками? Я считаю, что это вообще никуда не лезет. Все-таки мы не являемся ни друзьями, ни знакомыми, ни родственниками, не так ли? Так. Если учительница позволяет общаться на **ты**, то, значит, и мне можно. Вы как считаете?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Когда-то крестьянские дети (и моя прабабушка) обращались к родителям на вы. Не знаю, что это меняло в самоощущении, но мне бы не хотелось отдаляться от мамы на расстояние "вы". Что касается других людей - уважение к старшим сейчас, увы, потеряно. Это проявляется во всем: и в "ты", и в нежелании уступать место в транспорте, и в других мелочах.

В данном случае речь идет о личностном конфликте учителя и ученика. Если человек не нравится, ему не хочется говорить "вы". И тогда молодая энергичная злюка ищет морального оправдания своему хамству. Я вам его не дам: всем, кто старше вас, надо говорить вы, пока вас не попросят перейти на ты. Что при этом говорит учитель - его личное дело. Его поведение вас не оправдывает. Взрослость - это ответственность за свои поступки без оглядки на чужую вину и одобрение интернет-сообщества.

Comment: Недавно была свидетелем такой сценки на улице: малыш не более трех лет "боксирует" кулаками свою маму, гневно приговаривая при этом: "Вот тебе, вот тебе!" После этого думается, что лучше любовь на некотором отдалении, чем такая "близость". Мне кажется, что в прежнее время уважение к родителям, может быть, и начиналось, и закреплялось в сознании еще маленького ребенка с обращения на ВЫ. Только вот куда, когда и почему всё это исчезло?

Answer (score 5):

Можно и ВЫ так произнести, что в щель забиться захочется. А можно радоваться  и Ты обращению, если оно демонстрирует дружественность, заботу, любовь, если хотите. Когда я начинаю работать со старшеклассниками, с которыми раньше не была знакома, я обращаюсь к ним на ВЫ. Потом в процессе общения, по мере того как знакомимся ближе, перехожу на ты, это происходит естественно, потому что так и получается, что становимся ближе друг другу. А уж если я ребятишек знаю с 5 класса, то в десятом переход на ВЫ  был бы нарочитым и неестественным. У нас городок маленький, наверное, в Москве по-другому, а у нас отношение к детям как к своим детям, а с возрастом и как к своим внукам, дети это чувствуют и никому в голову не приходит протестовать против традиционного ТЫ. Дети, конечно, к старшим обращаются на Вы.

Comment: К сожалению, обращение на ТЫ имеет два совершенно противоположных оттенка значений. С одной стороны, это выражение особой дружественности и расположения к собеседнику, с другой - фамильярность, грубость, стремление унизить человека,указать ему  его место. Обращение к учащимся  на ВЫ должно быть основной формой, а переход на ТЫ - как исключение, если это удобно для работы и приветствуется обеими сторонами.

Comment: Поддерживаю ответ, расположенный выше.

Answer (score 2):

1. Считать кого-либо быдлом вообще не стоит. "Быдло" - это слово, используемое людьми с выраженным стадным инстинктом, для групп людей не соответствующих критериям их "стада".
2. Обращение "ты-ты" принято между хорошо знакомыми равными людьми. Между начальником-подчинённым как правило используется модель "ты-Вы", такой же тип обращений принят при общении взрослого с ребёнком. Для ученика учитель и взрослый, и начальник, поэтому если в школе не принят другой тип общения, то вариант "ты-Вы" в данном случае наиболее приемлем.

Comment: Вообще, по правилам школьного этикета, вошедшим даже в Уставы некоторых школ,к старшеклассникам положено обращаться на Вы. Однако во многом это зависит от сложившихся в данной школе традиций. Я, когда много лет назад работал в школе, обращался к ученикам 10-11 классов на Вы, и это было проявлением моего уважения к ним. А вот в годы моей учебы в школе учительница математики обращалась ко всем на "ты", но если ученик что-то натворил, она подчеркнуто говорила ему "Вы"

Comment: Тема действительно интересная ;) Я считаю, что это неверно –– обращаться на ты. Хорошо, тогда я с ней тоже на ты, раз уж она такой пример подает.

Comment: >Вообще, по правилам школьного этикета, вошедшим даже в Уставы некоторых школ,к старшеклассникам положено обращаться на Вы

@виктор1799, тут уже корпоративный этикет. В школах где доводилось учиться и преподавать мне и моим знакомым, такое было не принято. Слышал и о школах, где к учителю принято обращаться на "ты". В любом случае нужно смотреть правила самой школы. Также не считаю, что за обращение на "ты" к ученикам учителя можно считать "быдлом"

Comment: Зря. Не соблюдение etiguette :)

Comment: >Между начальником-подчинённым как правило используется модель "ты-Вы", такой же тип обращений принят при общении взрослого с ребёнком.  
  
Фу... Вот это уже действительно быдлячество, причем обоюдное.

Answer (score 1):

Какого возраста ученики?
Я думаю, что уж классу-то к десятому они уже заслуживают обращения "на Вы". 
Хотя тут какая-то недоговоренность есть в современных морально-этикетных установках.
Если "На ты" - это значит взаимно на ты. Но на отношения "учитель-ученики" и (реже)"родители-дети" это почему-то не распространяется.

Answer (score 1):

Я считаю, что учитель может к любому ученику обращаться на ты, но ученик не имеет права так разговаривать с учителем. Заслуживает ученик обращения на Вы или нет, а на ты называть учителя - просто хамство. В конце концов, даже если ученик взрослый и нету большой разницы в возрасте, учитель это учитель, и заслуживает соответственного уважения. А тем, кто считает что "раз учителю можно, то можно и нам", советую подумать а такой же модели поведения в других случаях. Если родители могут наказывать детей, значит и дети могут наказывать родителей, так что ли получается?

Comment: Слава Богу, что я не пошла работать по специальности (учитель биологии и химии)! Я бы не смогла работать с детишечками, у которых родители ставят вопрос "можно ли считать учителя быдлом"...

Comment: Бедные учителя... Вы бы лучше думали о том, чтобы дети побольше уважали тех, кто их учит, и сами учились хорошо, а не делали по восемь ошибок в каждом слове. А самоуважения (точнее, даже самовлюбленности) у современных подростков и так выше крыши.  
И, кстати, в заголовке "вы" должно быть со строчной буквы.

Comment: Что? В заголовке с большой буквы вообще-то

Comment: >И, кстати, в заголовке "вы" должно быть со строчной буквы.

>Что? В заголовке с большой буквы вообще-то  
  
Вот и поговорили....

Comment: Вообще-то, когда идет обращение не к кому-то конкретному, а ко всем, "вы" пишется с маленькой буквы. Или Вы, уважаемый behemothus, перепутали понятие строчной и прописной буквы?))))

Answer (score 1):

Пора на государственном уровне заняться правилами школьного этикета. И школьники, и учителя должны понимать, что они не у себя дома, что они  находятся в учреждении и связаны взаимными правами и обязательствами.

Думаю, что стандарт "ВЫ - ВЫ" должен быть нормой  начиная со среднего школьного звена (после 5-ого класса), все остальные обращения допустимы только в неформальной обстановке.

Скорее всего, кроме формы обращения, есть и другие темы, связанные с этикой поведения в школах.

Answer (score 1):

Согласен с [@София](/users/2203/%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%84%D0%B8%D1%8F): к обучающемуся надо обращаться на "Вы", начиная с некоторого возраста, порог которого требует обсуждения. Думаю, что с того момента, когда обучающийся становится совершеннолетним (примерно 8-й класс), учителя обязаны увидеть в нём себе ровню... В нашей школе (Базковская средняя Ростовской области) в начале 50-х годов (8 - 10-й классы) работал учитель русского языка и литературы  Андрей Иович Шевченко, выпускник Ленинградского университета. Он ко всем обучающимся старших классов обращался на "Вы". Было странно слышать это на фоне всеобщего "тыканья". Но это запомнилось...Он, между прочим, был женат на Пелагее Харлампьевне, дочери Харлампия Ермакова, основного прототипа Григория Мелехова ("Тихий Дон"). Пишу об этом просто к сведению - из любви к роману, учителю и к читателям, на которых роман, возможно, произвёл впечатление